# How to speed up the progress of transposing a data set

Tags: r, for-loop, transpose

For my thesis I'm using an sql dump that is very large. So far, I managed to open small segments of the sql dump in R. However, all the data is structured as follows:

X 
X 
X 
X

X 
Y 
Y 
Y

X 
Z 
Z 
Z

If I want to interpret the data more efficiently, the data should look like this:

XXXX 
XYYY 
XZZZ

To accomplish this, I've written a `for` loop that transposes the data. Unfortunately, due to the size of the data set (and my memory), this loop is really slow. Does anyone have an idea how to speed up the `for` loop or speed up the process in general? I've tried to use `dcast/reshape`, but it seems that these functions will not do the trick.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
DATAclean <- data.table()
for (i in c(1:100)){
  vector <- DATAtransed[,..i]
  vector <- na.omit(vector)
  StartCol <- seq(from = 1, to = (nrow(vector)), by = 4)
  Sys.sleep(0.001)
  print(i)
  flush.console()
  for (j in StartCol){
    new_data <- vector[c(j:(j+3))]
    new_data <- t(new_data)
    DATAclean <- rbind(DATAclean, new_data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave, that command only changes the data.table into a matrix with four levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the base R option below

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
        unname(split(seq_along(data), ceiling(seq_along(data) / 4))),
        function(k) data[k]
    )
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "X"  "X"  "X"  "X"
[2,] "X"  "Y"  "Y"  "Y"
[3,] "X"  "Z"  "Z"  "Z"
```

**DATA**

```
data <- structure(c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "Z", 
"Z", "Z"), .Dim = c(12L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be more efficient (especially regarding memory) to work on large files in a line-based manner, e.g. using the usual suspects on the unix/linux command line, or perl, python...

Assuming your data has one column as in your example, and you want to concatenate every 4 rows without any separator, removing empty rows, you could do:

```sh
awk 'NF' infile | paste -d ''  - - - - > outfile
```

Obviously, you could also wrap that in a `system` call in R to get the entire result into R:

```r
system("awk 'NF' filename | paste -d ''  - - - - ", intern=TRUE)
```